# jQuery Validate - Multiple Rules per Element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I have a form which I would like to validate certain fields as being required as well as being digits. I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply both rules to said fields.

Currently here is how I am applying only the required rule, displaying the message in a span I have built into my form.

```
    if (jQuery.validator) {
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo('#invalid-' + element.attr('id'));
        }
    });
}

$("#UserInputs").validate();


<label for="AvgGroupSize">Average Group Size:</label><br />
<span id="invalid-AvgGroupSize"></span>
<input type='text' id='AvgGroupSize' class='required' size='4' value='15'/> EEA's
```

How would I able to add a second validation rule (digits) to this field?

Thank you.

Comment: `class='required digits'` isn't working?

Comment: It does work, I didn't realize that was an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a class to your input:
`<input type='text' id='AvgGroupSize' class='required digits' size='4' value='15'/>` EEA's

if digits validation class doesn't exist yet you need to add i through: [Add Class Rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules#rules)

Another option might be is just adding rules to your input.

something like this:

```
$("#AvgGroupSize").rules("add", {
 minlength: 2
});
```

Read more on how to [Add rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Comment: Great, I didn't even realize you could add multiple classes to elements in HTML, much less being able to do it with a jQuery plugin. Thanks a lot!